# How can we assign bytes to uint256 variables in solidity?

Tags: solidity, bytes, uint256

I am confused of this.

when I write

```
uint256 internal ownerPrivateKey = 0xB0b;
```

Is this conversion implicit? how are we assigning bytes to a uint256 variable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can assign smaller integers to larger ones.

A byte is uint8. Not semantically, but from the bits points of view.